# How to retrieve data from Firestore with the MVVM pattern

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am creating an android application following the MVVM patron with the goal of retrieving data from a Firebase collection.

Before applying this pattern, I did proof of concept and I was able to retrieve data from the Firebase collection. But once I apply MVVM, I am not able to get the data from that collection, my screen does not show anything. I am not able to return the data from the repository to be painted on the screen.

This is my code:

Model:

```
data class PotatoesData(
    val modifiedDate: String,
    var potatoes: List<Potato>
)
```

```
data class Potato(
    val type: String,
    val site: String
)
```

State:

```
data class PotatoesState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val potatoes: List<Potato> = emptyList(),
    val error: String = ""
)
```

ModelView:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PotatoesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getPotatoesDataUseCase: GetPotatoesData
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(PotatoesState())
    val state: State<PotatoesState> = _state

    init {
        getPotatoes()
    }

    private fun getPotatoes() {

        getPotatoesDataUseCase().onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.value = PotatoesState(potatoes = result.data?.potatoes ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error   -> {
                    _state.value = PotatoesState(
                        error = result.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred"
                    )
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = PotatoesState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

UseCase:

```
class GetPotatoesData @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PotatoRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<PotatoesData>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            val potatoes = repository.getPotatoesData()
            emit(Resource.Success(potatoes))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            emit(Resource.Error("Couldn't reach server. Check your internet connection."))
        }
    }
}
```

Repository implementation:

```
class PotatoRepositoryImpl : PotatoRepository {

    override suspend fun getPotatoesData(): PotatoesData {

        var potatoes = PotatoesData("TEST", emptyList())

        FirestoreProvider.getLastPotatoes(
            { potatoesData ->
                if (potatoesData != null) {
                    potatoes = potatoesData 
                }
            },
            { 
                potatoes 
            }
        )

        return potatoes 
    }
}
```

Firestore provider:

```
object FirestoreProvider {

    private val incidentsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirestoreCollection.POTATOES.key)

    fun getLastPotatoes(
        success: (potatoesData: PotatoesData?) -> Unit,
        failure: () -> Unit
    ) {

        val query: Query = orderBy(FirestoreField.CREATED_DATE, Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
        val querySnapshot: Task<QuerySnapshot> = query.get()

        querySnapshot
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                if (!querySnapshot.result.isEmpty) {
                    val document = querySnapshot.result.documents[0]
                    val potatoesDataDB: PotatoesDataDto? = document.toObject(PotatoesDataDto::class.java)
                    potatoesDataDB?.let {
                        success(potatoesDataDB.toPotatoesData())
                    } ?: run {
                        success(null)
                    }
                } else {
                    success(null)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                failure()
            }
    }

    private fun orderBy(field: FirestoreField, direction: Query.Direction): Query {

        return incidentsRef.orderBy(field.key, direction)
    }

}
```

I am thankful for any kind of help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will probably find this useful. [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: I think you might also be interested in reading this article, [How to make a clean architecture Android app, using MVVM, Firestore, and Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8).

Comment: Oh, I don't have a paid version on Medium! It's a good time to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is in the way of how you are handling Firestore callbacks. in `FirestoreProvider`: the callback will fire later than the function `getLastPotatoes` returns. Try to make that function suspend and use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) to wait for the callback and return it's result. It will look something like:

```
suspend fun getLastPotatoes() = suspendCoroutine <PotatoesData?> { continuation ->

    val query: Query = orderBy(FirestoreField.CREATED_DATE, Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
    val querySnapshot: Task<QuerySnapshot> = query.get()

    querySnapshot
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            if (!querySnapshot.result.isEmpty) {
                val document = querySnapshot.result.documents[0]
                val potatoesDataDB: PotatoesDataDto? = document.toObject(PotatoesDataDto::class.java)
                potatoesDataDB?.let {
                    continuation.resume(potatoesDataDB.toPotatoesData())
                } ?: run {
                    continuation.resume(null)
                }
            } else {
                continuation.resume(null)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            continuation.resumeWithException(...)
        }
}
```

`suspendCoroutine` suspends coroutine in which it executed until we decide to continue by calling appropriate methods - `Continuation.resume...`.

In your `PotatoRepositoryImpl`:

```
override suspend fun getPotatoesData(): PotatoesData {

    var potatoes = PotatoesData("TEST", emptyList())

    try {
        val potatoesData = FirestoreProvider.getLastPotatoes()
        if (potatoesData != null) {
            potatoes = potatoesData
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // handle Exception
    }
   
    return potatoes 
}
```

Comment: I have made your changes and it works correctly! I was not aware of the suspendCourutine method, it has been very useful. Thanks!